# What should I do if the tool package fails to run when I integrate the HUAWEI AppGallery Connect SDK to Eclipse?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I had recently planned on integrating the Crash SDK to my app. However, my app was developed through Eclipse and the integration process was different from that in Android Studio.

By referring to the official materials, I downloaded the tool package and used it to generate an Eclipse project package.

However, when the build.bat file in the aar2eclipse/aar directory was executed according to the procedures in the document, an error was reported in the command line. The error information was as follows:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task ' assembleRelease ' not found in root project ' aar '.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 1):

1. I first thought that the problem might be caused by my company's intranet. But when I connected to the Internet, the problem remained unsolved.
2. Then I guessed that it might have something to do with the Android development environment.

I borrowed a colleague's PC to execute the build.bat file, and it that did the trick. Therefore, I was able to conclude that the problem was caused by incorrect configurations in the Android development environment. I compared the configurations on the two PCs and found that the environment variables were different. ANDROID_HOME was missing from the environment variables on my PC.

Cause
Huawei's Eclipse tool package is unable to run properly and reports an error without the ANDROID_HOME variable.

Solution: Right-click This PC and choose Properties from the shortcut menu. In the displayed dialog box, click the Advanced System Settings tab and then click Environment Variables. In the System Variables dialog box, create a new ANDROID_HOME parameter.

Set the value to the installation path of the local Android SDK, and the problem will be resolved, as shown below.
[image]

Reference:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-get-started#h2-1587519820720